# Highlight HTML using Remarkable and Highlightjs

Tags: javascript, html, highlightjs

I'm having trouble getting the `highlight` function to execute when using `Remarkable` to highlight HTML code. I'm taking from the example [here](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable#syntax-highlighting):

```
var md = new Remarkable({
    html:true,
    langPrefix:'lang-',
    highlight: function (str, lang) {
    alert('highlighting'); // never executes!
    if (lang && hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
      try {
        return hljs.highlight(lang, str).value;
      } catch (err) {}
    }
    try {
      return hljs.highlightAuto(str).value;
    } catch (err) {}

    return ''; // use external default escaping
  }
});

var test = md.render('<code class="lang-js">var x = 1;</code>');
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhz9oma1/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Remarkable works when you give it text written in markdown, not HTML. It generates the HTML for you. If you wanted to write out the HTML yourself, you don't need Remarkable ;)

So, your test line should look like this:

````
var test = md.render('``` js\nvar x = 1;\n```\n');
````

(normally, text is pulled from a text area, so you don't need the "\n" in there, you would just hit enter)

Here is the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fhz9oma1/7/